# Read specific part of xml document with VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I guys, I have a xml with this model:

```
<XML>
  <IdValue id="1">
    <Value a="1" b="2" c="3" />
  </IdValue >
  <IdValue id="2">
    <Value a="10" b="20" c="30" />
  </IdValue >
</XML>
```

So i want to read, with a `VB.NET` program,  the value of the attributes `a`, `b`, and `c`, in based on the value of the attribute id of the node `IdValue`.

Can yo help me ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: No, sorry. It's the first time that i used XML files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy using VB.Net's XML literals and Linq-to-XML.

Given the following XML:

```
Dim xml = <XML>
            <IdValue id="1">
                <Value a="1" b="2" c="3" />
            </IdValue >
            <IdValue id="2">
                <Value a="10" b="20" c="30" />
            </IdValue >
           </XML>
```

You can extract the values you are looking for as easy as

```
Dim result = From id In xml.<IdValue>
             Select New With { .Id = id.@id,
                               .a  = id.<Value>.@a, 
                               .b  = id.<Value>.@b,
                               .c  = id.<Value>.@c }

For Each item in result
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("id:{0} a:{1} b:{2} c:{3}", item.id, item.a, item.b, item.c))
Next
```

**Output:**

> id:1 a:1 b:2 c:3
>   id:2 a:10 b:20 c:30

If you're interested in a single `<IdValue>`, you can add a `Where` clause; for example:

```
Dim result = From id In xml.<IdValue>
             Where id.@id = 2
             Select New With { .Id = id.@id,
                               .a  = id.<Value>.@a, 
                               .b  = id.<Value>.@b,
                               .c  = id.<Value>.@c }
```